# CLIPBOARD and PRIMARY registers don't work on my Linux

Tags: vim, clipboard, copy-paste, yank

If I want to copy/paste something to/from a register I have no problem.
For example if I'm in Visual Mode and I press `"ay` the selected region get correctly copied to register `a` (and if I press `"ayy` in Normal Mode, the line under the cursor get correctly copied into `a`).

During the sequence I can see the characters I pressed in the bottom bar.

If I try to hit one of the sequences `"*yy`, `"*dd`, `"+yy` or `"+dd`, when I press the double quotes they appear in the bottom bar, but when after this I press `*` or `+` the sequence in the bottom bar disappear and if I complete the sequence, it doesn't copy anything to the CLIPBOARD and PRIMARY selections.

System: **ArchLinux**

Window manager: suckless **DWM**

Terminal: bash on suckless **ST**

Comment: Does your Vim have clipboard support? If you run `vim --version`, or the `:version` command inside Vim, do you see `+clipboard`?

Comment: No. It is version 8.2 and has `-clipboard`. Is there a way to add clipboard support?

Comment: the `-` means the feature is disabled... I just added an answer, hopefully that will work for you. Clipboard support is a compile time option (need to link to the X libraries), so you need to install a different package for it to work correctly.

Comment: They disappear for me too but it works—happens a lot when I paste

Comment: For me it didn't work, but thanks to @filbranden 's solution it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `+clipboard` support in your Vim.

On ArchLinux, you can get a Vim with `+clipboard` support by installing the `gvim` package.

See [Vim Installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Installation) on the ArchLinux wiki, more specifically this note:

> The `vim` package is built without Xorg support; specifically the `+clipboard` feature is missing, so Vim will not be able to operate with the primary and clipboard selection buffers. **The `gvim` package provides also the CLI version of Vim with the `+clipboard` feature.**

The `gvim` package will include a new `gvim` command for a GUI version of Vim, but it will *also* include a regular console `vim` command, only that one will have support for `+clipboard` when running inside a terminal attached to an X11 display.